# Find the sum and the product of sextic equation

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I know $x-1$ is a factor of this equation, which will reduce it to quintic, but I am stuck at finding the other $5$ solutions.

$$2x^6+2x^4-x^3+7x-10=0$$

Comment: sorry, my bad, just corrected it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just aiming to find the sum and product of the roots, then look no further.

Using Vieta's equations, the sum of the roots is $\displaystyle \frac{0}{2}=0$, and the product of the roots is $\displaystyle \frac{-10}{2}=-5$.

Look up Vieta's equations.